# Extract a substring from a string, as well as the remainder of the string

Tags: r, string, substr

I want to store the first character of a string in a variable, and the rest of the string in another variable. For example:

```
x <- "foo"
prefix <- substr(x, 1, 1)
suffix <- substring(x, 2)
```

However, it seems a bit wasteful to call `substr` and `substring`. Isn't there a way to extract both the substring, and the remainder of the string (the "difference" between the substring and the original string) at once?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
substring(x, c(1, 2), c(1, nchar(x)))
# [1] "f"  "oo"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea using regex,

```
strsplit(gsub('^([A-z]{1})([A-z]+)$', '\\1_\\2', x), '_')
#[[1]]
#[1] "f"  "oo"
```

Comment: doesn't look much handier than with `substr`/`substring` ;-)

Comment: Misread it. I thought the problem was to only use 1 function 1 time to do the operation

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `str_split` from the `stringr` package:

```
require(stringr)
x<-c("foo", "hello", "world")
str_split(x,"(?<=.{1})",2)
#[[1]]
#[1] "f"  "oo"
#[[2]]
#[1] "h"    "ello"
#[[3]]
#[1] "w"    "orld"
```

Comment: What does the string `"(?<=.{1})"` mean?

Comment: It's a `regex`, in the `perl` flavour. See `?regex`. It means: "look for a pattern that follows a single character".

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(data_frame(x), x, into = c('prefix', 'suffix'), sep=1)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#  prefix suffix 
#* <chr> <chr>
#1     f    oo
#2     h  ello
#3     w  orld
```

#### data

```
x<-c("foo", "hello", "world")
```

Comment: Nice! I could even use this one, since I load `tidyr` in nearly all my scripts...